# Add new Text Field dynamically on Submit event

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

this is Antika. I have started learning to code since a few days back, and am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, and basics of **dart/flutter**

**Developer Level:** Beginner
**Project type & language:** I'm developing a **Simple Notepad App**, using **flutter**.

In my Project,
I want to **dynamically add new `TextField` widgets** on the screen, 
once the user hits enter or *clicks the next button* ('➡️'), *in mobile devices*, **Just after the TextField in focus**, and not to the end of the List.

***Outline***

User types text >> Clicks Submit  
    >> Keeping in mind `TextField`  in focus >> Add another `TextField` just after this one.  
        >> The User feels like entering a new line.

For e.g., as is shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: being a beginer is great because you are starting and will be good one day, but you must search before posting questions this is basic question and is easily searchable
https://findnerd.com/list/view/Create-EditText-on-button-click-in-Android/2723/
see this for example

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list with initially one `TextField` widget and `onSubmitted` adds another `TextField` to the list.

```
class MyWidget

 extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<TextField> textFields = [];
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    textFields.add(_buildTextField());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: textFields
    );
  }

  TextField _buildTextField(){
    return TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      onSubmitted: (_){
        setState((){
          textFields.add(_buildTextField());
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ❤️.  That sounds pretty much what my want. Can you please guide me how to do that...

Comment: Added a code snippet

Comment: I'm **getting this error** - [https://ibb.co/tM2zgLt](https://ibb.co/tM2zgLt). I want to insert the `TextField` just after the textField in focus, and not in the end of the list. I am still a beginner in Flutter, and can use all the help I can get.

Comment: the onSubmitted, you can insert the textfield where you want it to go

Comment: Can you please guide on how to achieve that