# How do I get notesControllers['key']!.text work?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to post a note. Within the note I have several `TextField` one of which I would like to repeat like this illustration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008564/add-new-text-field-dynamically-on-submit-event). The answer to that question I implemented in my code. Works exactly as I want but I can't get it to post or print the input of each created `TextField`. Playing around with it the most I've gotten is 1 line.

So I did more digging and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766139/flutter-create-dynamic-number-of-texteditingcontrollers). I tried the answers but I haven't quite gotten it.

Here I had to add null check to get rid of `text` error:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                          if (notesControllers['key']!.text.isEmpty) { // HERE
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text("All fields are required")));
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              loading = true;
                            });
                            await FirestoreServiceEdit().insertNote(
                                notesControllers['key']!.text, // HERE
                                widget.user.uid);
```

[image: text error]

[image: _CastError]
I'm not sure what to do.

Below is my current code with the other TextFields cut out:

```
class AddNoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  User user;
  AddNoteScreen({
    required this.user,
  });

  @override
  State<AddNoteScreen> createState() => _AddNoteScreenState();
}

class _AddNoteScreenState extends State<AddNoteScreen> {
  TextEditingController noteController = TextEditingController();
  // var noteController = TextEditingController(text: str);
  Map<String,TextEditingController> noteControllers = {};
  // List<TextEditingController> noteControllers = [];

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  bool loading = false;

  List<TextField> textFields = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   textFields.add(_buildTextField());
   // TextEditingController noteControllers = TextEditingController(text: str);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var stringListReturnedFromApiCall = [];

    Map<String, TextEditingController> notesEditingControllers = {};
    // var textFields = <TextField>[];
 textFields.add(_buildTextField());
    stringListReturnedFromApiCall.forEach((str) {
      var notesEditingController = new TextEditingController(text: str);
      notesEditingControllers.putIfAbsent(str, () => notesEditingController);
      return textFields.add(TextField(controller: notesEditingController));
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF162242),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: ListView(
                  children: textFields,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
              loading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (notesControllers['key']!.text.isEmpty) { // HERE
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text("All fields are required")));
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              loading = true;
                            });
                            await FirestoreServiceEdit().insertNote(
                                notesControllers['key']!.text, // HERE
                                widget.user.uid);

                            CollectionReference notes =
                                firestore.collection('notes');
                            QuerySnapshot allResults = await notes.get();
                            allResults.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot result) {
                              print(result.data());
                            });

                            setState(() {
                              loading = false;
                            });

                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Add Note",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF162242)),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextField _buildTextField() {
    return TextField(
        // controller: notesControllers,
        //controller: TextEditingController(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefix: Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 8,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        autofocus: true,
        onSubmitted: (String str) {
          setState(() {
            textFields.add(_buildTextField());
           //  notesControllers['key']!.text = str;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

```
class NoteModel {
  String id;
  String notes;
  String userId;

  NoteModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.notes,
    required this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModel.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return NoteModel(
      id: snapshot.id,
      notes: snapshot['notes'],
      userId: snapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

```
class FirestoreService{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(String notes,String userId)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "notes":notes,
        "userId":userId
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You declared the `noteControllers` as a map.

Not TextEditingController but Map

To use it like this:
`noteControllers['key'].text`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got some errors so I updated my question

Comment: I recommend that you learn the map first.